# Label rotation in amCharts not working properly

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I need to rotate the x-axis labels 45 degrees. What I did is as below:

I have added `chart.labelRotation =45`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/s8La6g7m/)

It is not working!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`labelRotation`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelRotation) is a property of `categoryAxis`, not chart's property. So you need to apply it to `chart.categoryAxis`:

```
chart.categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45;
```

Here's your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8La6g7m/1/).

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Using AmCharts.makeChart:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( chartId, {
....
....
"categoryAxis": {
   "labelRotation": 45,
....
},
....
....
}
```